# Passing parameters to eloquent with ajax - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel app where I want to get some ajax data when I click a link inside a table cell. What I want to do is pass a parameter to use on an eloquent query. Here is the javascript:

```
$('#monthly_table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-controls', function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var row = table.row(tr);
      //row.data().kpi_id -> the parameter to be passed
      $.get('valid-kpi-data?kpi_id='+row.data().kpi_id, function(data){
          console.log(data);
      });
});
```

And here is the `route.php`

```
Route::get('/validate/valid-kpi-data', function(){
    if(Request::ajax()){
        $id = $_POST('kpi_id'); //this is the parameter i want to be passed
        $year = Carbon::now()->subYear()->format('Y');
        $kpis = DB::table('reports')
                         ->where('year', '>=', $year)
                         ->where('is_validated', 1)
                         ->where('kpi_id',$id)
                         ->take(25)
                         ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
                         ->get();
        return Response::json($kpis);
    }
});
```

I have tried this in several ways, and I know that the `id` is passed as a query string with the request. However i cannot get anything back. The below image is what it turns every time.

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just use `$.post` instead of `$.get` :)

Comment: Your `$.get()` URL path is `valid-kpi-data` while the defined Laravel route path is `/validate/valid-kpi-data`. You're missing the `validate/` from the the beginning of the URL from the AJAX request.

Comment: @Hackerman if i use `$.post` it throws `Error 405 method not allowed`

Comment: Now i have it..just change this piece of code: `$id = $_POST('kpi_id'); ` to this one: `$id = $_GET('kpi_id'); `

Comment: @Bogdan it still doesn't change anything even after i fixed that

Comment: @Hackerman tried that one also. nothing changes

Comment: @Hackerman it shows an error `Function name must be a string` because of that line of code. If i remove it it works but i need that to filter the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$.getJSON('validate/valid-kpi-data/'+row.data().kpi_id, function(data){
      console.log(data);
});
```

Then change the route declaration as given below:

```
Route::get('/validate/valid-kpi-data/{kpi_id}', function($id){
    if(Request::ajax()){
        // $id is available now so use $id in where clause
    }
    //...
});
```